# firefox and multiple outlook accounts

Tags: firefox, email, microsoft-outlook

I'm working on company X which collaborates with company Y, on a common project. I got email accounts from both companies and I'm using Firefox on a Mac book pro m1 laptop. I'm reading my emails from outlook.office365.com/ or outlook.office.com/.

Is there a way to use a single browser window(!) and different tabs to check emails from both accounts? (I can use one normal window and private/incognito one, but I would prefer not to)

Are any extensions/other settings I could use? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the Mozilla article
[Put your multiple online personalities in Firefox Multi-Account Containers](https://blog.mozilla.org/en/uncategorized/introducing-firefox-multi-account-containers/).

It describes using the
[Firefox Multi-Account Containers add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/?utm_source=blog.mozilla.org&utm_campaign=firefox_frontier&utm_medium=referral).

This add-on is described as :

> Firefox Multi-Account Containers lets you keep parts of your online life separated into color-coded tabs. Cookies are separated by container, allowing you to use the web with multiple accounts and integrate Mozilla VPN for an extra layer of privacy.

[image]

Comment: it works really nice. thank you @harrymc